# runas /savecred error 1311 no logon server

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch, login, runas

Computer: Windows 8.1 Pro on company domain

I have a program that needs to be run occasionally for testing purposes, and is installed and uninstalled regularly.  I am not a domain administrator, and part of the install process involves changing user groups and sharing permissions that will fail if I install from my domain account.  The solution from IT is to use a local machine account to install and remove, and I've been using a .bat file for running the program without switching user accounts, as follows:

```
runas /user:LocalUserAccount c:\myprogram.exe
```

This works fine enough, but I'd like to not have to type in the password every time I run the program for testing.  When I do this:

```
runas /savecred /user:LocalUserAccount c:\myprogram.exe
```

I receive this:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - c:\myprogram.exe
1311: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

From what I understand of the /savecred flag, it's supposed to ask me for the password on the first run, and save the credentials in the Windows Credential Manager after that, but it doesn't.  I've tried adding the logon credentials for LocalUserAccount manually, but that doesn't work either.  Any help or pointers are appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

Rebooted the computer and it worked fine.  Not sure why that would be needed after modifying the .bat file, but I won't question it.

Answer (score 1):

If this machine belongs to a domain and not connected to this network, /savecred will not work.
Please connect to the network and try again.